# Авторизация через uLogin и получение данных

Tags: ulogin, авторизация, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Хочу сделать отзывы на сайте, для этого нужно чтобы тот кто оставляет отзыв авторизовался через соц.сеть. Мне нужно после авторизации параметр callback передал в функцию ucall данные имени и после этого записал их в нужные поля формы автоматом.

Как это сделать? 
Я добавил код самого uLogin

```
<script src="//ulogin.ru/js/ulogin.js"></script> 
<a href="#" id="uLogin" data-ulogin="display=panel;fields=first_name,last_name;providers=vkontakte,odnoklassniki,mailru,facebook;hidden=other;redirect_uri=;callback=autoriz">
<img src="http://ulogin.ru/img/button.png" width=187 height=30 alt="МультиВход"/></a>
```

написал до одури простую функцию

```
<script> 
function autoriz() { 
   document.getElementById('nameyou').value = first_name; // заносим данные в поле с id - nameyou } 
</script>
```

как понял нужно еще получить токен пользователя. Честно не знаю как это сделать...

Comment: @Alexander Sizintsev, Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось. приведите код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас на сайте uLogin http://ulogin.ru в личном кабинете есть отличный пример функции коллбэка, работающей с токеном [раздел Виджеты]

Comment: что-то я не вижу раздела виджеты =/ и примера

Comment: Войдите в личный кабинет (кнопка Войти), и создайте первый сайт.

Comment: спасибо, сразу не понял =)